# Implementing IEnumerable, Lists

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I found [this MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx)

It describes implementing `IEnumerable` in order to use the object in a `foreach` loop. My question is, in the example's main method it uses a `Person` array to initialize the `People` `class`.  Can I use a `List< ClientEntry>` rather than an array of `ClientEntry`?  What is required to implement a List for a certain class?

Comment: `List<People>` already implements IEnumerable, so there would be no need for you to implement it yourself.

Comment: So I can use People in list the way it is written already?

Comment: You can already use foreach with a `List<People>` if that's what you mean.

Comment: What I'm really asking is, is there a certain requirement for using a class in a List, Dict, etc.?  Or does it not really matter.  For example Person is the business object, People is just an array of persons that implements IEnumerable  Would I use Person for the List?  And in that case what is the point in implementing People as IEnumerable if I can just use a List<Person >?

Comment: I'd recommend sticking to one question at a time when asking on SO. "Can I use `List<Person>` instead of `Person[]` to implement enumerable" seem to be reasonable enough. Asking why would you pick one approach over another generally turns out to be opinion based question and will be closed as such...

Comment: I'm not asking why to pick one over the other I was asking if it was possible.  My wording just wasn't great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one can see in the documentation about [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this class has the signature:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[DebuggerDisplayAttribute("Count = {Count}")]
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, 
    IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

As you can see, it already implement `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`. This means every `List<T>` instance can be used in a `foreach` loop:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
//add people
foreach(Person p in people) {
}
```

Furthermore there are no restrictions on `T` (you can use any type you like). Otherwise the signature should contain a

```
public class OtherList<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : class
```

the `where T : ...` means `T` should satisfy a certain constraint. There is no need at all to start implementing `List<T>`s yourself.

A `List<T>` is a `class`. Since C# does not allow multiple inheritance, one can only make a `Peolpe` an element from `List<People>` by adding inheritance:

```
// Collection of Person objects. This class 
// implements IEnumerable so that it can be used 
// with ForEach syntax. 
public class People : List<Person> {

    public People(Person[] pArray) {
        this.AddRange(pArray);
    }

}
```

In that case you don't have to implement `IEnumerable<T>` and other interfaces. But only if you want to add additional behavior (or modify some behavior) there is no reason to use `People` over `List<Person>`.

Comment: What's an example of where T : class?  e.g. When would you use something like that, what kind of class would you put there?

Comment: @shenk: not *a* `class`, but `class`. This means [`T` can only be a class, interface, delegate or array type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) not an `enum` or `struct`. For instance to enable reference equality `==`.

Answer (score 2):

It is surely possible to use a `List<Person>` instead of `Person[]`. You will just need to replace all the backing variables, changing their type from array to List and change relevant code as well. The point however, is that List is already enumerable so it doesn't make much sense to implement another `IEnumerable` using a List as internal storage, unless you are doing something special like skipping certain elements based on dynamic conditions etc.

Comment: I don't know if I've got my English right, but when you say "surely possible" it makes it sound to me like you've never done it, it's hard to make it work, and you recommend against it. I would suggest using the phrase "very straightforward", rather than "surely possible", as I think that's the sense you're after.

Comment: @Enigmativity what I meant was exactly that it's possible but not worth the effort. And you're right that I have never done that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a custom collection to use a class in a list.  There is already a generic collection out of the box that can be used for any class (via generics).

You can do this now,

```
[Flags()]
public enum AddressTypeValue : ushort
{
    Personal = 0,
    Business = 1,
    POBox = 2,
    Inertnational = 4
}
public class Address
{
    public AddressTypeValue AddressType { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public Person() 
    {
        Address = new Address() { AddressType == AddressTypeValue.Personal };
    }
}
```

//some code using it in a list

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

public List<Person> GetPeopleMatchingFirstName(string firstNameToMatch)
{
    var people = DBContext.People.Where(p => p.FirstName.BegintsWith(firstNameToMatch) || p.FirstName.EndsWith(firstNameToMatch) || p.FirstName.Equals(firstNameToMatch, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    return people.ToList();
}
```

Now if you want a strongly typed collection where you want to have custom logic for Add/Delete/Insert/Indexing etc, then and only then would you need to implement IList or IEnumerable.

There is any easier way to do that though because you just implement List via inheritance and override the thing you want to change.  In the event the behavior you want to change is not virtual (cannot be overridden) then you might need a custom implementation of List.

```
public class MyCustomListOfPeople : List<Person>
{
    public override Add(Person person)
    {
        //send email that a person was added or w/e you want to do here
        base.Add(person);
    }
}
```

If you want a readonly list, where things can't be added then you can just use ReadOnlyCollection where you pass in  a base list.  Once constructed nothing can be added or removed from the ReadOnlyCollection.  This is useful for things like state lists, zip codes, report data, etc etc.

It is also easy to wrap a List and expose it as IEnumerable without allowing access to it's add/delete etc methods.

```
public class AnotherListOfPeople : IEnumerable<Person>
{
    private List<Person> internalList = new List<Person>();

    //internal logic to manipulate people

    public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return internalList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return internalList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Doing the latter allows you to surface a private list's built in enumerator to something else.. So the enumerator interfaces are being exposed by the wrapping class those allowing your class to be enumerated with Linq and foreach while blocking callers from having direct access to the List.

There are many more ways you can leverage the power of a List or IEnumerable, but generally you can just use a List for whatever you need and rarely need to wrap one or implement the interfaces for a custom collection.